# How does a Root or Authorative DNS server reply to the correct Anycast server?

Tags: dns, anycast

Let us say there are 2 recursive Anycast DNS servers, A and B, with IP 200.0.0.0.

A needs to look up 'example.com' and queries Root server C.

However, in the routing table of the BGP router where C is located, 200.0.0.0/24 points to the network where B is located as the shortest path.

So how does A get its response? Would not C's reply be sent to B?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/server and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Sorry about that. Do I delete the question?

Comment: The sys will or will not delete it in some days, depending on the traffic.

Comment: 200.0.0.0 is no valid IP address, unless you've got a /6 network...

Comment: This is a question about anycasting and is definitely on-topic here.  This is a fine example of the toxic moderation problem we seem to have. :/

Comment: @JeffWheeler, I considered this a layer-3 problem, but since it is my first question here, I didn't want to start arguing. Whoever closed it, apparently didn't resolve the reason either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anycast resolvers' queries from their clients arrive on an anycasted address, but the resolvers perform upstream DNS resolution using a unicast address.

```
                   /-----------------\
                   | DNS server with |
user ---192.0.2.53-| one anycast and |-203.0.113.2---ns1.example.com
                   | one unicast IP  |
                   \-----------------/

In this example, anycast IP: 192.0.2.53
Unicast IP: 203.0.113.2
```

Typically, the way this works in the DNS server's operating system is the main address on its Internet-facing NIC is e.g. `203.0.113.2` while the anycast address(es) like `192.0.2.53` are secondary addresses, often configured on a loopback interface.  If you'd like more details about that part of things, the [Server Fault SX](https://serverfault.com/?_gl=1*1x91zp7*_ga*MTI1Nzk5OTk1OC4xNjA2NTE1MzE4*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2NjQ0ODc0MC4yNC4xLjE2NjY0NDkwMzQuMC4wLjA.) is a good resource.